# ASP.NET setting a path for file with VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So this is a pretty dumb question, and one I am clearly misunderstanding for whatever the reason.  I have an ASP.net project and the default aspx page loads a file.  I made a class to deal with file handling, in it I hard coded the local directory to where that file is.  I want to make that path relative to the default.aspx page.  I can't figure out how to do that.  I have read a lot of stuff on MSDN, and it makes simple sense, but when I put it to code I can't seem to get it right.

I feel my answer is here, I understand what it is saying but I can't translate that to my program.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx. Code such as

```
Dim rootPath As String = Server.MapPath("~")
```

makes sense to me but I can't use 'Server' for some reason.

I have used this spot of code to supplement my problem for now.

```
string=System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()
```

Any help leading me on the right....path, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Dim rootPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")
```

from your class.

Comment: That worked, I guess I needed to prefix it with the HTTPcontext.Current classes.  Thanks for the help, stupid me.